# RESET.CSS blocks styling for <em> in Safari only...why?

Tags: css, fonts, safari, google-webfonts

I'm using Eric Meyer's reset.css, as found here:

http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

For reasons unknown, it is blocking my definition for `<em>` in my main style sheet *ONLY* in Safari. In all the other browsers, my `<em>` definition works as instructed (selecting the correct font, etc.)

The only work-around I've found for this is to *remove* "em" from the listing in the reset.css file. Fortunately, that does not pose a problem for my site in any way in any of the browsers. It does fix the Safari `<em>` problem, for when the "em" is removed from the reset.css file, then the `<em>` text is rendered correctly in Safari.

Has anyone else experienced this with Safari, and can anyone suggest a remedy better than simply removing the "em" from the reset.css?

**SOURCE CODE FOR TESTING**

Here is the text of a file that calls three CSS files. In all browsers except Safari, the text displays with the correct font definitions. Only when the `em` definition in the RESET.CSS file is eliminated will italic be rendered on Safari. Why?

[index.php]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" />
<p>This should be Muli Roman</p>
<p><em>This should be Muli Italics</em></p>
<p><strong>This should be Open Sans Bold</strong></p>
<p><em><strong>This should be Open Sans Italics</strong></em></p>
```

[reset.css]

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, 
em,
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section{display:block;}
body{line-height:1;}
ol, ul{list-style:none;}
blockquote, q{quotes:none;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after{content:'';content:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
```

[fonts.css]

```
@font-face{font-family:'Roman';font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/BkuZCUxEYxRfSu-XBj9_CA.eot');src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/BkuZCUxEYxRfSu-XBj9_CA.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
local('Muli'),
local('Muli-regular'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/zscZFkjVRGyfQ_Pw-5exXPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/minRpKQdEvXRRS8oAbAtWvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/BfQP1MR3mJNaumtWa4Tizg.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=5laWPvb-IgmGJk9r92y1Hw#Muli') format('svg');}
@font-face{font-family:'Italic';font-weight:400;font-style:italic;src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/vurWTAYiHMPVScIey50dUQ.eot');src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/vurWTAYiHMPVScIey50dUQ.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
local('Muli Italic'),
local('Muli-italic'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/YxNEAWILjDc466nftZdqXuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/DSOyST5zmfghBgRIogdupevvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/muli/v7/AQQ1r0_czneVCtTD9ckSEA.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=Ok1ULmeTg1kfss3jIu3xZQ&skey=f22af9a5d2e9fc47#Muli') format('svg');}
@font-face{font-family:'Bold';font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot');src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
local('Open Sans Semibold'),
local('Open-Sans-600'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSqRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSonF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSllIn5tFQcqMuf-jhyJP0ps#OpenSans') format('svg');}
@font-face{font-family:'BoldItalic';font-weight:600;font-style:italic;src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxo8mkAiYpFywqG2RvpzBnTU.eot');src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxo8mkAiYpFywqG2RvpzBnTU.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
local('Open Sans Semibold Italic'),
local('Open-Sans-600italic'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxsiAiQ_a33snTsJhwZvMEaI.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxuw_rQOTGi-AJs5XCWaKIhU.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxi8cqLH4MEiSE0ROcU-qHOA.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxuVmfClkf66xvxL1SWm4y8M#OpenSans') format('svg');}
```

[site.css]

```
p {line-height:1.875;padding:0 0 0.75em 0;}
body, .roman{font-family:'Roman', Arial, sans-serif;}
em, i, .italics{font-family:'Italic', Arial, sans-serif;}
strong, b, .bold {font-family:'Bold', Arial, sans-serif;}
em strong, strong em, ib, bi, .italics .bold, .bold .italics {font-family:'BoldItalic', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Comment: From the site you linked to: "I don’t particularly recommend that you just use this in its unaltered state in your own projects. It should be tweaked, edited, extended, and otherwise tuned to match your specific reset baseline."

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem that's being addressed. The reset.css file as presented should NOT interfere with the realization of the `<em>` tags differently on Safari. Please contribute if you can address the issue from experience and with sound advice.

Comment: I understand the problem, but just wanted to provide sound advice in that a CSS reset is *designed* to be modified. It is not going to accommodate every situation and really should not be used as-is. I contributed as a comment instead of an answer because I wasn't directly answering the question, but wanted to provide valuable information to future visitors who might listen to the author of that CSS reset and remove unnecessary items or items that cause undesirable behavior.

Comment: Also, you might wish to try and break the problem down and provide the minimum code necessary to replicate the behavior you're seeing. It will go a long way in clueing us in on why the `em` styles are not being applied. Knowing nothing about your implementation makes it difficult to provide an answer. Have you tried adding `!important` to the properties that are being overridden/ignored?

Comment: @Quantastical Fair enough, I've supplied the code for the four files needed to reproduce the problem. The text renders correctly on every browser except Safari, which requires the `em` definition in the reset.css file to be eliminated in order to display the intended italic. Any clue?

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem and have given my best attempt at a legitimate answer.

Comment: @Quantastical It's a great answer...thanks for testing it and discovering the cause. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the problem and the simplest way to remedy it is to explicitly define the `font-style` property in your `site.css` as such:

```
p {line-height:1.875;padding:0 0 0.75em 0;}
body, .roman{font-family:'Roman', Arial, sans-serif;}
em, i, .italics {
  font-family:'Italic', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style:italic; /* added */
}
strong, b, .bold {font-family:'Bold', Arial, sans-serif;}
em strong, strong em, ib, bi, .italics .bold, .bold .italics {font-family:'BoldItalic', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Safari is reading the `font:inherit;` portion of the `reset.css` that you are using and interpreting that as an override of the browsers native `font-style:italic;` definition of `em` elements with a final computed value of `font-style:normal;`.

To rectify this, one must either re-include the `font-style` in `reset.css` or in their `site.css` files. I'm not sure if that is a bug in Safari's implementation of WebKit, though. It appears that Chrome is also computing the final output as `font-style:normal`, which makes me wonder why theirs is rendering as italic.